# chrome does not load certain pages

Tags: firefox, google-chrome

Hi I have some issues on chrome, I have ubuntu 16 and neither chrome nor firefox load any pages but youtube and fb. It loads google as well but only results of search and when I enter one of them it doesn't load. It might be my router's problem, I have been searching around the web and nothing works for me so far.

Comment: Hi, travisspears, do other devices on your home network have issues connecting to the other sites? And what errors do you receive when you try to visit these sites?

Answer (score 1):

the problem could be in your ip tables.
turn fire wall off.
flush the ip tables

> sudo iptables -F

try again without a firewall. If all works well try firewalld.

I had a similar problem and switched to firewalld. Its found in the Ubuntu Software and it works great. All the services can be added in the GUI.
Smpts, imaps, http, https, dhcp, dns. I would use the drop zone, nothing out, only in and drops every attempt to get in to your OS.

> sudo systemctl enable firewalld
>   firewall-cmd --set-default-zone=drop

add the desired services in the gui (permanent, every start-up) then

> sudo systemctl restart firewalld.service

you can add transmission/or other service using runtime (temporary until next reboot) and NEVER go into the file system to change anything